# .rb doesn't save files

Tags: ruby, save

I'm very new with ruby and I can't understand one thing. 
When I use this command from command prompt I can successfully save files.

```
irb
copy = "test"
File.open("output.html", 'w') {|f| f.write(copy) }
```

but when I save it to .rb file nothing happens. Script seems to be working, but it doesn't save the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
copy = "test"
File.open("output.html", 'w') {|f| f.write(copy) }
```

Why?

Comment: Maybe it saves it, but not where you are looking for it :)

Comment: Yes, I feel like an idiot now. I was searching 2 hours for solution. Doh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Dir.pwd` in irb to get your current working directory.  This directory should hold your output.html file.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing obvious wrong with your code -- it should indeed write to the file "output.html". I assume that the actual problem is not with ruby or your script but elsewhere. Perhaps you're not looking for the output file in the right location?